# Android Programming error in json convertion

Tags: android, json, string

http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html
 i used the above link. same coding 
error is Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

Comment: You used that link to produce this error ?

Comment: that link is not enough post your code and logcat.

Comment: there is no error in coding but when i run the application on my phone it is not displaying the data from database it is showing me the error "errorg.json.jsonexception value br of type java.lang.string"

Comment: errororg.json.JSONException : value <br of type java.lang.string cannot be  converted to JSONObject .........this is my error

Comment: Actually you are parsing a string value to JSONObject definitely it will give you the error, you need to parse it as String e.g. String brValue = jsonInstance.getString("br");

Comment: Furthermore, to explain the problem you are facing, you should put your json response format and parsing code with your question, so that I can find the problem area.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this exception(JSONException) because your php service does not return a valid json and as you said in comment it seems that your php service is returning a HTML snippet with `<br>` instead of a proper JSON String.